# Match and compare two data frames using pandas and update based on missing value

Tags: python, pandas

I have two Dataframe with the following values.

```
Dataframe 1
    Colum1   Primary    
0    test1     1234
1    test2     4567
2    test3     56789
3    test4     8799
```

```
Dataframe 2
    Colum1   Primary  Category      
0    test     56789      A
1    test     8799       B
```

For each row in column, check for primary value. if true, update Dataframe 1 with the Category Value.
The final Output should be.

```
Dataframe 1
    Colum1   Primary    Category
0    test1     1234
1    test2     4567
2    test3     56789        A
3    test4     8799         B
```

Comment: `df1.merge(df2, on=['Column1', 'Primary'], how='left')`

Answer (score 1):

try `pandas.join`:

```
df1 = df1.join(df2[['Primary','Category']], by='Primary', how='left')
```

`df2[['Primary','Category']]` - selects only 2 columns for joining

`by='Primary'` - key for joininig

`how='left'` - keeps all df1 rows even without matches in df2

Answer (score 1):

Always faster and neater to use map where possible.
Put the codes or df2 into dict

```
d=dict(zip(df2.Primary,df2.Category))
d
```

Map dict onto df1

```
df1['Category']=df1['Primary'].map(d).fillna('')
df1
```

Outcome

[image]